# getActionBar(), getSupportActionBar() returns java.nullpointer.exception

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have set appcompat file to the projectproperties. There is no error in errorlog and neither in problems. The logcat shows the error java.nullpointer.exception in getActionBar. When i comment the line, the application runs well. 
Suggestion required on how this problem can be resolved

```
ActionBar actionBar= getActionBar();

View cview= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_menu, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(cview);
```

Build Gradle File consist of the following

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bumpintomums"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}
```

Error Logcat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bumpintomums/com.current.amnepal.bumpintomum.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.current.amnepal.bumpintomum.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:83)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I extended ActionBarActivity to use getSupportActionBar() while extended Activity for getActionBar().In both the cases i got null pointer exception

Comment: post logcat, or error

Comment: Paste ur imports as well.

Comment: Post stack trace. Also just try to run this activity without accessing actionbar or getting referece to it and check if it is showing.

Comment: I am still unable to run my project.If anyone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can get from your question is that you are looking to design custom Action Bar for your Application,right?

If yes then below code may help you out:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
            bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            bar.setCustomView(R.layout.row);
            bar.show();
    }
}
```

Please Note that enabling customenabled property on action bar is important for your Actionbar to implement custom view.

**bar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)**

And also no need to use to LayoutInflator you could directly feed action bar custom layout by using

**actionbar.setCustomView(*your layout file*)**

Comment: It doesnot allow me to use getActionbar(). It gives Java.lang.nullpointerexception. I am using api 21 fo this project.

Comment: Are you sure you are calling getActionbar() after setContentView() method has been called in onCreate()?

Comment: @ranjana i noticed that you are using Appcompat v7 library,right?In that case,you should call **getSupportActionBar()** ,extend ActionBarActivity and define style/Theme.AppCompat.*childs* in your manifest.

Comment: And if supporting Android 1.x/2.x devices is not that important for you, i would recommend you using native ActionBar available after Api level 11

Comment: Check the updated question. I am using the latest android version to compile. As you said I tried to call getSupportActionbar(), it also showed the same error and I am using native actionbar.

Comment: Since you are working with Native Action Bar, try changing your App Theme to something like ***Theme.Holo.Light***.See if that works out...

Comment: <style name="customtheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
I used this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67629/discussion-between-droidwala-and-ranjana).

Answer (score 2):

You may check whether the "Theme" applied in the Activity

If it is a theme without ActionBar, you will get null if you try to get action bar.

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light, this is the parent theme i used for the customized theme.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `activity.getActionBar()` will only return a null, not a exception. please give your code and printStackTrace()

A nullpointer.exception only occurs when you call the null's method,such as `null.getActionBar()`

[actionbar guide for more](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

PS: you use `getActionBar().hide();` since getActionBar() is null, so your code is `null.hide()`, the exception occurs. if you want to use/hide actionBar, read the guide above.

**NullpointerException-workround:**

```
if(getActionBar() != null)
    getActionBar().hide();
```

**use theme in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" ... >
```

**extends ActionBarActivity**

```
public class FoorActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

**fill your menu**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
 getActionBar().hide();

Logcat shows the error in second line and it says it is caused by java.nullpointer.exception

Comment: you use `getActionBar().hide()` while the `getActionBar() == null`

Comment: I did what you say but i am unable to run actionbar in any of my classes. if shows error java.lang.nullpointerexception

Comment: have you create your menu? `@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}`

Comment: Here i am getting a appcompat error. Wen i try to use appcompat for versio 19 it shows error in values 21 files error. 
if i use version 21 it shows error in all getActionbar() methods giving nullpointerexception

Comment: I did the way you said but it doesnot display actionbar for my application

Answer (score 0):

I had Theme set to NoActionBar in Android manifest file. Moreover, my gradle build version and com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+' were out of sync.
See if you have this problem.